# How do I search for source code in Netbeans 7.2?

Tags: search, ide, project, netbeans-7

Simple question. How do I search for code in my project within NetBeans 7.2 IDE? for example I want to find a Class name or any string of code, let's say I use this string "Apple is a fruit" in 10 Classes and 20 Methods and I want a list of all the locations it's being used in.

Note: I used Google Search and looked at relevant threads before posting this here, but all I found was how to make search programs, obviously a confusing topic for search engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the function in Edit> Find in Projects..